# Wording to explain why our app is refusing to run on a jailbroken (hacked) iOS device

Tags: error-message

When our [app detects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/413242/642706) it is running on an iOS device that has been jailbroken (hacked to circumvent Apple's *App Store* and the *In-App Purchase* payment system), we replace our usual user-interface with a simple message. The message explains that instead of normal operations, this app is refusing to run. All functionality is removed.

How can I word this message? I want to avoid sounding offensive or accusatory, for two reasons:

- The user may be nearly innocent. Perhaps their cousin was "doing them a favor" by jailbreaking the device, but the user did not comprehend the nature of the act.
- There may be some other weird problem (bug) triggering our jailbreaking-detection into reporting a false-positive.

Comment: Perhaps you could start be explaining to us why you consider this detection necessary.

Comment: @IMSoP Jailbreaking means the user can defeat the In-App Purchase payment system of Apple's App Store, thereby giving them unlicensed access to our encyclopedia-like content.

Comment: Aha. That would be an important detail I would want to see in the message as a user: "Our app relies on the in-app purchase system provided by the Apple App store; since this can be circumvented on a jailbroken phone, this application will refuse to run in that situation." (There are plenty of things wrong with that wording, but leading with the *reason*, rather than the *policy* seems important to me.)

Comment: @IMSoP That's a helpful thought.

Comment: "The user may be *nearly* innocent." There are plenty of legitimate reasons to jailbreak that are not to avoid paying for apps/content.  Your presumption of guilt is already pretty offensive.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you should consider that you're fighting an uphill battle—if your app is popular enough, [the other guys are probably able to patch your app to remove any checks you may perform](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Bypassing_Jailbreak_Detection).

If you do decide it's worth the effort, the first place to start is [Apple's guidelines for alerts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/Alerts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1).

As with any other error message, you should include three things:

1. A very short error title, phrased in the imperative (users should be able to read this quickly without thinking too hard)
2. A (slightly) longer error description with justification of the behaviour (this is useful for users to Google the problem)
3. A clear call to action for the user (what the user can do next)

In this case, the seemingly appropriate behaviour according to Apple's guidelines is:

> **Jailbreak Detected**
>   Your phone appears to be jailbroken, and so for security reasons [App Name] cannot be loaded.
>   [More Info] [Quit]

That having been said, [Apple explicitly says you should not quit your app programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/_index.html). Since your app is apparently non-functional on jailbroken devices, I'm not sure what alternative you have to a **Quit** button. Perhaps a deliberately non-functional version of your app's starting screen (in which case the button just becomes **OK**).

In my example, the **More Info** button would take the user to Safari with details of your justification, and—importantly—instructions for how the user can report a false positive to you.

For completeness, here are some other examples of a similar message from other apps (including one from Apple's iBooks):

[image: Example jailbreak detection message]
[image: Example jailbreak detection message]
[image: Example jailbreak detection message]
[image: The way iBooks handles jailbreak]

And here's a pretty familiar one from Microsoft that is deliberately worded to avoid being too accusatory toward the user:

[image: Microsoft's piracy detection behaviour]

Comment: I would avoid the quit alternative. I've had a couple of apps refused because of in-app termination functionality. In those cases, the apps had to run in a certain geolocation regions to be allowed, and we chose to force the users to terminate if they were in a different region. Not appreciated by Apple.

Comment: @Babossa: so how did you solve it? With an "OK" button that takes the user to a non-functional app?

Comment: Something like that, yes. I think the alert comes back when you tap OK. It's not a good user experience really...